Equivalent definitions of an ordinary cusp
In Multidimensional Real Analysis I, p. 144, it mentioned (without proof) that the two following definitions of an ordinary cusp are equivalent:
Definition 1: If $\phi: I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^3$ curve, an ordinary cusp at a point $x^0$ is that, after application of a local $C^3$ diffeomorphism $\Phi$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined in a neighborhood of $x^0$ with $\Phi(x^0)=0$, the image curve $\Phi\circ\phi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ in a neighborhood of $0$ coincides with the curve $\gamma: t\rightarrow(t^2, t^3)$.
Definition 2: Let $\phi:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^3$ curve, $0\in I$ and $\phi(0)=x^0$. Then $\phi$ is said to have an ordinary cusp at $x^0$ if $\phi'(0)=0$ and if $\phi''(0)$ and $\phi'''(0)$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
It's easy to verify that definition 1 implies definition 2, but I got stuck on how to prove definition 2 also implies definition 1. Basically, we need to construct the $C^3$ diffeomorphism $\Phi$ that satisfies definition 1. Can you give some hint on how to construct such a diffeomorphism? Thanks.
